# Recursive database actions

Tags: object-oriented, .net, database, vb.net

I am been using a code pattern for recursive database actions in my applications.

I create two class objects of a database table, singular one (e.g Agent) for holding single record with all fields definition, plural one (e.g Agents) for database actions of that records like, select, insert, delete, update etc. I find it easy using the code pattern.

But as the time runs I find it somewhat laborious to define same database action functions in different classes only differing in datatype.

How can I make it good and avoid defining it again and again?

Sample code of a class file representing the class definition:

```vb
Imports EssenceDBLayer

Public Class Booking
#Region "Constants"
    Public Shared _Pre As String = "bk01"
    Public Shared _Table As String = "bookings"
#End Region

#Region " Instance Variables "
    Private _UIN As Integer = 0
    Private _Title As String = ""
    Private _Email As String = ""
    Private _contactPerson As String = ""
    Private _Telephone As String = ""
    Private _Mobile As String = ""
    Private _Address As String = ""
    Private _LastBalance As Double = 0
#End Region

#Region " Constructor "
    Public Sub New()
        'Do nothing as all private variables has been initiated'
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal DataRow As DataRow)
        _UIN = CInt(DataRow.Item(_Pre & "UIN"))
        _Title = CStr(DataRow.Item(_Pre & "Title"))
        _Email = CStr(DataRow.Item(_Pre & "Email"))
        _contactPerson = CStr(DataRow.Item(_Pre & "contact_person"))
        _Telephone = CStr(DataRow.Item(_Pre & "Telephone"))
        _Mobile = CStr(DataRow.Item(_Pre & "Mobile"))
        _Address = CStr(DataRow.Item(_Pre & "Address"))
        _LastBalance = CDbl(DataRow.Item(_Pre & "Last_Balance"))
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region " Properties "
    Public Property UIN() As Integer
        Get
            Return _UIN
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _UIN = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return _Title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Title = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Email() As String
        Get
            Return _Email
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Email = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ContactPerson() As String
        Get
            Return _contactPerson
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _contactPerson = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Telephone() As String
        Get
            Return _Telephone
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Telephone = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Mobile() As String
        Get
            Return _Mobile
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Mobile = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Address() As String
        Get
            Return _Address
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Address = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property LastBalance() As Double
        Get
            Return _LastBalance
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            _LastBalance = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

#Region " Methods "
    Public Sub [Get](ByRef DataRow As DataRow)
        DataRow(_Pre & "Title") = _Title
        DataRow(_Pre & "Email") = _Email
        DataRow(_Pre & "Contact_person") = _contactPerson
        DataRow(_Pre & "Telephone") = _Telephone
        DataRow(_Pre & "Mobile") = _Mobile
        DataRow(_Pre & "Address") = _Address
        DataRow(_Pre & "last_balance") = _LastBalance
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class

Public Class Bookings
    Inherits DBLayer

#Region "Constants"
    Public Shared _Pre As String = "bk01"
    Public Shared _Table As String = "bookings"
#End Region

#Region " Standard Methods "
    Public Shared Function GetData() As List(Of Booking)
        Dim QueryString As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}{1} ORDER BY {0}UIN;", _Pre, _Table)
        Dim Dataset As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim DataList As List(Of Booking) = New List(Of Booking)

        Try
            Dataset = Query(QueryString)
            For Each DataRow As DataRow In Dataset.Tables(0).Rows
                DataList.Add(New Booking(DataRow))
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            DataList = Nothing
            SystemErrors.Create(New SystemError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace))
        End Try
        Return DataList
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetData(ByVal uin As String) As Booking
        Dim QueryString As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}{1} WHERE {0}uin = {2};", _Pre, _Table, uin)
        Dim Dataset As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim Data As Booking = New Booking()

        Try
            Dataset = Query(QueryString)
            If Dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 1 Then
                Data = New Booking(Dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0))
            Else
                Data = Nothing
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Data = Nothing
            SystemErrors.Create(New SystemError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace))
        End Try
        Return Data
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Create(ByVal Data As Booking) As Boolean
        Dim QueryString As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}{1} WHERE {0}uin = Null;", _Pre, _Table)
        Dim Dataset As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim Datarow As DataRow
        Dim Result As Boolean = False

        Try
            Dataset = Query(QueryString)
            If Dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Datarow = Dataset.Tables(0).NewRow()
                Data.Get(Datarow)
                Dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Add(Datarow)
                Result = UpdateDB(QueryString, Dataset)
            Else
                Result = False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Result = False
            SystemErrors.Create(New SystemError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace))
        End Try
        Return Result
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Update(ByVal Data As Booking) As Boolean
        Dim QueryString As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}{1} WHERE {0}uin = {2};", _Pre, _Table, Data.UIN)
        Dim Dataset As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim Result As Boolean = False
        Dim DataRow As DataRow = Nothing

        Try
            Dataset = Query(QueryString)
            If Dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 1 Then
                DataRow = Dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)
                Data.Get(DataRow)
                Result = UpdateDB(QueryString, Dataset)
            Else
                Result = False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Result = False
            SystemErrors.Create(New SystemError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace))
        End Try
        Return Result
    End Function

    Public Shared Function UpdateBulk(ByRef DataList As List(Of Booking)) As Boolean
        Dim Result As Boolean = False

        Try
            For Each Data As Booking In DataList
                Update(Data)
            Next
            Result = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            SystemErrors.Create(New SystemError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace))
        End Try

        Return Result
    End Function

    Public Shared Function FillGrid() As List(Of Booking)
        Return GetData()
    End Function
#End Region
End Class
```

Comment: Just for clean up: 1. to see how to do generics in VB.Net ( see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79(v=vs.100).aspx ) and 2. if you would KoolKabin, if you believe pdr's answer about ORM is the solution to your question, please click accept answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're talking about is called object-relational mapping.

You could do this, but it will be a fair amount of effort. Luckily many people have run into this same question before, answered it and open-sourced that solution. I suggest looking at using one of those solutions.

[nHibernate](http://www.nhibernate.com/) is just one example but is a popular and mature solution.

Edit: More accurately, object-relational mapping is mapping fields to columns, objects to tables and object relationships to table relationships, so it does exactly what you want and (optionally) much more.

Answer (score 4):

To add a little to PDR's answer, since you have mentioned VB.NET, if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher you can use the [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx) to generate all of the basic classes and the supporting CRUD methods of those classes.

Comment: its greatful when we have some of your favourite site link for information on Entity Framework

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0